# Where to set individual blog quotas?

Tags: multisite, admin, uploads, media

I am administering a self-hosted, multi-site Wordpress 3.1.x site with a few hundred sites.

10 users have requested to have their quotas increased to 1GB.

I can't do it for everyone, but I would like to do it for these 10 sites.

How can I set blog media quota on a site-by-site basis ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious, is there any special reason why you haven't upgraded your 3.1.x install?

Comment: I don't see any reason why we should support such old versions - core doesn't either. Close voting as too localized. Can be reopened after an update.

Comment: I'd love to update Wordpress but the organization I work for creates documentation and training for our employees on how they should use Wordpress as a CMS.  We have a certain number of plugins that are working correctly now, and won't work when upgraded.  Yes, we will upgrade to a stable version soon ( probably not the latest ).

Comment: I can't help to notice: *"how they should use WP as CMS"*, keeping it up-to-date and not relying on not-maintained plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your site's Network Admin page -- usually something like `example.com/wp-admin/network/`.  Go to **Sites » All Sites**.

Mouse over the site that you need to edit and select **Edit** in the menu that appears.

Now select the **Settings** tab.  Scroll down to the bottom (or near the bottom, depending on whether you have plugins installed that add more settings at the bottom). You're looking for the **Site Upload Space Quota** setting.  Put the appropriate number of MB in that box -- if you're updating a site's quota to 1GB, for instance, you'd put `1024` in the box.

If there's nothing in the box, it will use your network's default quota.

Comment: I never noticed that you're running 3.1.x.  I can't say for sure if my instructions will work that far back.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it there - all the way at the bottom